# Sidereal astrology Python library

Tags: python

I'm trying to get planetaries positions (in the zodiac wheel) and the aspects (trines, oppositions, etc.) for a Python app. My main issue is that all the solutions I've installed until now are based on the tropical system, and I would like to have the Lahiri or Fagan-Bradley sidereal astrology ones.

I've found two great solutions :

- Flatlib : https://github.com/flatangle/flatlib/tree/master/flatlib
- Astrology API : https://astrologyapi.com/western-api-docs/api-ref/164/western_horoscope

**Flatlib** is doing **perfectly** what I'm looking for, i.e. :

```
date = Datetime('2015/03/13', '17:00', '+00:00')
pos = GeoPos('38n32', '8w54')
chart = Chart(date, pos)

sun = chart.get(const.SUN)
print(sun)
<Sun Pisces +22:47:25 +00:59:51>
```

...but it uses the tropical system with the Swiss Ephemeris. Soooooo sad :'(

**Astrology API** is providing Western and Vedic astrology. But as Vedic astrology can give me the good planetaries positions, they don't offer aspect and other functions that I need. They redirect me on their "Western Astrology" offer, but this is tropical only.

Is anybody has found a solution for that type of needs ?
Many thanks :)

Comment: Take a look at Skyfield if you want andesine astronomical data. It won't give you the astrological info directly, but it'll be a good start if you know the relationships between the bodies of interest.

Answer (score 2):

There are two branches of flatlib:

1. master
2. sidereal

You can calculate Lahiri or Fagan-Bradley sidereal from sidereal branch

[Sidereal Astrology](https://github.com/flatangle/flatlib/tree/sidereal)

Answer (score 0):

Please use swisseph for vedic astrology .
There is not much documentation there but you can search there